# Showing a relation for green's function in single site impurity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, greens-functions, second-quantization

The Hamiltonian is given as

$$H = \sum_k \epsilon_k c_k^{\dagger} c_k + V \sum_k (c_k^{\dagger}d + d^{\dagger}c_k) + \epsilon_d d^{\dagger} d$$.

Here, the $d$ operator denotes the annihilation and creation on the site of impurity.

If we denote the Green's function for this Hamiltonian as
$$G = \frac{1}{E-H+\iota \eta}$$,
then I have to prove the relations
$$(E-\epsilon_d+\iota \eta)<d|G|d>-\sum_k V <k|G|d> = 1$$
$$(E-\epsilon_k+\iota \eta)<k|G|d>- V <d|G|d> = 0$$

I have no idea how to proceed. If $|d>$ was an eigenstate of $H$, then we would have $(E-\epsilon_d+\iota \eta)<d|G|d> = 1$ by the definition of Green's function, but in this case where my Hamiltonian is off-diagonal, I do not know if I should simply try to diagonalize my Hamiltonian or there is an easier way of seeing these.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193859/matsubara-green-function-of-anderson-impurity-model?rq=1

But that question is unanswered and follows a slightly different approach towards the solution

Answer (score 0):

Label the states as $|k>$ and $|d>$. It is then easy to see that
$$H|k> = \epsilon_k |k> + V|d>$$
and $$H|d> = \epsilon_d |d> + V |k>$$

Now, by definition
\begin{align}
(E-H + \iota\eta)G &= 1 \\
(E-H+\iota\eta)<d|G|d> = <d|d> &= 1 \\
(E-\epsilon_d + \iota\eta)<d|G|d> - V<k|G|d> &=1
\end{align}

Similarly,
\begin{align}
(E-H + \iota\eta)G &= 1 \\
(E-H+\iota\eta)<k|G|d> = <k|d> &= 0 \\
(E-\epsilon_k + \iota\eta)<k|G|d> - V<d|G|d> &=0
\end{align}